# How would the 'error' property not be a valid property or method of ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-cordova

I have a mobile cordova application. When I run it and try to login. I get the following error:

JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'error'

This is the block of code that it is referencing for the error:

```
 $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: 'POST',
           data: { domainName: domain, username: username, password: password, appId: appId }


       })

           .done(function (json) {


               if (json.success) {
                   that.set("isLoggedIn", true);
                   token = json.token;
                   username = username;
                   isAuthenticated = true;
                   $('#show-Loader').hide();
                  window.location("#esig");


               }
               else {
                   navigator.notification.alert("No User Found", function () { }, "Login failed", 'OK');
                   //alert(json.error);
                   $('#show-Loader').hide();
                   return;
               }

           })
           //For some reason the following 'Property or Method' is not supported by $.ajax() 
      .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
          navigator.notification.alert('Unable to Connect to Server' + '\n' + ' Please check Settings.', function () { }, "Connection Failed", 'OK');
          $('#show-Loader').hide();
      });
   },
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I would be receiving this JavaScript error? Essentially I am wanting it to through the error that it can't connect to the server. That is what I am testing.

Comment: Use `.fail()` instead of `.error()`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.fail()` instead of `.error()`. (`.error()` doesn't exist)

You can either do

```
$.ajax({
    success: function() { ... },
    error: function() { ... }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({ ... })
    .done(function() { ... })
    .fail(function() { ... })
    .always(function() { ... });  //<-- optional
```

The latter is recommended.